# Moving files from onedrive on a laptop to an external hard drive

Tags: laptop, external-hard-drive, microsoft-onedrive

I have a serious problem with my PC (another question with this will follow later), so I am having to use my laptop (Windows 10, pretty normal configuration). The laptop storage is small (56 GB).

I work as a professional translator. I recently received 3 files, 2 very large (42 GB and 40 GB) and 1 large (14 GB) from a customer containing a load of photos and graphics.
While I still had the PC available, I stored these on onedrive and had no trouble accessing them on the PC.
When I try to read any of these files, I keep getting messages that there is insufficient space available to copy or download these files. The problem is obviously the laptop storage capacity, I have nearly 1 TB space available on onedrive.

I bought an external hard drive (2 TB) to try and resolve the problem. The intention was to move (not copy) the files off onedrive straight onto the external drive. Plenty of space available on both, right?
No chance. The message keeps coming back that I have insufficient storage space to "copy" (not "move") the files. I am running into potential deadline problems with my customer and I need to get at these files. I have no other computer available to me and I am not the most technical geek out there, but I have a very logical mind when it comes to problem solving.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: On Mac you can get around this by setting your system &/or browser's default download folder to be on the external. I can't test for Windows.

Comment: The OneDrive website may allow you to download these files directly, through your browser, and when you download them you can specify the directory they should download to

Comment: How are you downloading, using what software? perhaps a download manager can help solve the problem, as far as I can see this saves to external drive directly: https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/

Answer (score 1):

Open your personal OneDrive site. You should be able to right click on your Taskbar OneDrive icon and choose "view online" or something like that.

Find the files you're trying to download there in OneDrive in your web browser and then download them there in the browser. Use the method appropriate in your browser to choose the folder you wish to download the files to and choose the external drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with OneDrive locking me out for weeks, Microsoft stating I was over my limit because OneDrive started backing up all my system folders that I had never included originally. The more I tried to fix it, the more it doubled in size until it put my PC at a complete standstill. I finally got some results and am finally running smooth, so try this...

First you can try to just pause the syncing long enough to move the file. Pause is an option on the icon for OneDrive (cloud) in the taskbar's system tray.

That didn't work for the amount of moving I needed to do. OneDrive continued to restart automatically and sync while I was working, so it did little good toward moving files. To stop the restarts, I went to the Task Manager and disabled OneDrive on the Startup tab (don't forget to reenable when done). Still, I could move the files, but a copy remained locked in OneDrive (i.e. still a copy only even though the "Move" function was working). I could, however, now delete the OneDrive copy but saw it would take forever to compare and delete the many files I needed to for space.

Until I turned the sync settings entirely off at the source, no amount of moving files came off my OneDrive space. To turn the syncing entirely off, go to the taskbar icon for OneDrive (cloud) in the system tray, right click on the icon, and select *Settings>Sync and backup>Manage Backup*. Turn off ALL OneDrive backups until you are finished moving. If you leave any on, it may interfere with moving correlated files. As long as I had "Documents" still being backed up, multiple other folders remained locked up as well and prevented my moving. Suggestion: while still in settings, check *Settings>Account>Choose folders*. You should be able to uncheck all folders or something is still locked to sync which could prevent moving.

Note that my best results came from deleting files from the Windows Explorer on my PC rather than the OneDrive online files ... some files would remain in explorer even though deleted online but not vice versa. Also note that the space used will remain used up until you resync and empty the OneDrive trash in the online files at https://onedrive.live.com.

Some decisions I made after this were to stop using OneDrive for any but a few files, like OneNote and Outlook (files that are so intertwined with MS apps). I will not be putting files in the system folders again (Documents, Desktop, Downloads, Pictures) to avoid Microsoft adding back a sync I don't want during their upgrades as they apparently did. Also, because the OneDrive processes took over my processor and slowed my PC startup to full stop and lagged endlessly, I will likely keep it disabled at Startup ... I will be using Google or Dropbox for most of my backups and sharing where I can, as their cloud services have never impacted my PC performance. Maybe later Microsoft will clean these problems up for my reconsideration.

Hope something here helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).